# Docker interpreting concatenated variables with backticks

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Up until recently when using Docker Compose, the concatenated environment variable `NC_DB` did not contain backticks following interpretation. Am I doing something incorrectly, missing a Docker setting, or is this possible a Docker bug?

**.env**

```bash
POSTGRES_DB="mydb"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="mypass"
POSTGRES_USER="myuser"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
environment:
    NC_DB: 'pg://postgres:5432?u=${POSTGRES_USER}&p=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}&d=${POSTGRES_DB}'
```

**Prior, expected result:**

```
NC_DB          pg://postgres:5432?u=myuser&p=mypass&d=mydb
```

**Current result:**

```
NC_DB          pg://postgres:5432?u=`myuser`&p=`mypass`&d=`mydb`
```